# Why I have defined a js function,but the brower prompt that can not find the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the `document.load` I call the global functions `alertabc()`,I have defined it,but but the brower prompt that can not find the function.

```
<script>
function alertabc(){
    alert('abc');
    clearInterval(s);
}
var s;
$(function () {
    s = setInterval("alertabc()", 100);
});
<script>
```

Comment: is your 's' button working ok ?

Comment: Just as general practice, don't pass strings to `setInterval()`.  Use `setInterval(alertabc, 100)` in this case.

Comment: Your script doesn't have a closing tag. It has a second opening tag instead.

Comment: @Jay **Never** edit the code of the question.  If the OP makes a mistake in the code, the onus is on them to fix it, not us, for that mistake could be why the code isn't working in the first place.  You can format it, but don't add things that weren't there before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **cookie** said, your `script` tag is not closed,

```
  <script>
    function alertabc(){
        alert('abc');
        clearInterval(s);
    }
    var s;
    $(function () {
        s = setInterval(alertabc, 100);
            //good practice --^--as Brad said
    });
  </script>
//-^ do close by putting / forward slash
```

Comment: Thanks,Can you tell me why  change `alertabc()` to `alertabc` in the setInterval is a good practice?I see the example in the w3school is also write the `alertabc()`.[the setInterval](http://www.w3school.com.cn/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: You are using "alertabc()" which is need to `eval()` during the execute, use of eval is not good into javascript, it's in global scope and performance issue also. So avoid to use function name within quotes `""` as you did in your question.